# How to add typescript to existing vue3 project?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli

I have the following `package.json` file:

```json
{
    "name": "view",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet": "^0.6.1",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.3.1",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "gpxparser": "^3.0.8",
        "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
        "postcss": "^8.3.6",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.2.7",
        "typescript": "^4.3.5",
        "vue": "^3.0.0",
        "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
        "vue3-openlayers": "^0.1.38",
        "vuex": "^4.0.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.0-beta.3",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.0-beta.3",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^5.0.0-beta.3",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.0-beta.3",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
        "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
        "prettier": "^2.2.1",
        "sass": "^1.26.5",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
    }
}
```

How can I add typescript to this vue3 project?

I use yarn as package manager, and when I tried to install typescript via
`yarn add typescript`, it did install it to the project but I can't use TypeScript in my components.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your project is using Vue CLI run `vue add typescript` on command line

Docs: [@vue/cli-plugin-typescript](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/typescript.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't install vue with ```yarn global add @vue/cli```. It gives me a success message, but when I run ```vue --version```, it says vue not found. I am using Windows and tried installing it as Admin. Any ideas? Or should i ask a seperate Question?

Comment: But from `package.config` it seems you are using Vue CLI already so I expected you have it installed already. Whatever. Seems like an issue with yarn. You will find a lot of issues if this kind if you google it. It's been some time I'v used yarn (switched to pnpm). You can try to run `yarn global bin` - this should print the *folder where yarn will install executable files for your package.*. Check that you have this folder in PATH. https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `ERROR  Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-service/generator/template/src/App.vue' from '/var/www/html/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-typescript/generator/template/src'`